# Is there a systematic way (via iText or otherwise) to replace placeholder items in a PDF report generated by ReportViewer?

Tags: .net, itext, reportviewer, rdlc

I have found that one of the Microsoft Reporting controls (the Chart) is inadequate for my needs. Since these controls aren't extensible, I've extended the functionality of a WPF control and am saving the control as a graphic. Unfortunately, ReportViewer's image control doesn't support vector graphics, either. Therefore my goal is to generate the PDF from ReportViewer with certain "placeholders" (e.g. a rectangle item), and then come behind with iTextSharp and add the vector graphic on top of these placeholders. Since the report length flows based on the input data, I can't know the coordinates of these placeholders before getting them.

I can't think of a way to include a PDF field in the RDLC, which would be nice since iText has the GetFieldPosition() method. Furthermore I know there is iText's PDFWriter.GetVerticalPosition() method, but this is really only useful if you've moved the cursor to that location in the PDFWriter. Truth is, I'm still trying to get my head around iText and PDF. It is *vast*.

So my two questions that refer to each other:

1. What kind of placeholder should I use in the RDLC designer that can be systematically identified afterwards and have its position queried?
2. How would I go about getting this position?

Thanks in advance!

-Brandon

Comment: Can you create annotations? They are easiest to retrieve the coordinates of and they also are easiest to remove.

Comment: @mkl: I'm sorry, mkl, this is going to take another day to answer since Visual Studio 2012 update majorly bungled my install this morning. It is not clear whether and how the MS Report Viewer PDF export deals with IDs or annotations, nor if there are properties that can be associated with the .RDLC items which will effect these characteristics in the exported PDF. Microsoft Reporting isn't for PDFs really, you know, and if there's an event I can hook into during ReportViewer rendering of PDFs, I'm not aware of it. Thanks for your help, though, I appreciate it. I'll be back..

Comment: Is it possible to define form fields (like Buttons, text fields, ...)? PDF form fields are named and, thus, can easily be found. Furthermore their coordinates can be extracted quite easily, and after processing the form fields can be easily removed.

Comment: @mkl: I'm afraid not, based on my experience and some scouring of the MSDN forums/Google, there is no way to put input elements onto the report which would then be exported to PDF. The export mechanism can render to image formats (including vector format images, incidentally) which causes it to be basically static reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My imperfect, but working solution is to use text item placeholders that match the background to mark the positions in the .RDLC report. After generating the PDF, these are identified by way of inheriting iTextSharp's LocationTextExtractionStrategy (as per [this entry by greenhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577789/extract-text-and-text-rectangle-coordinates-from-a-pdf-file-using-itextsharp/8825884#8825884)). In my current test environment the above is copy-pasted verbatim and only deviates in the RenderText() override, which does not add the TextChunk to the list unless `info.GetText()` is an appropriate placeholder string.

Snippet of placeholder extraction:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx strat = new LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx();
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
   PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, strat);
```

The native vector image type is WMF, and can be inserted at the absolute location of the placeholder text. To do so for the first placeholder in the list, then:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("output.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
   using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
   {
      using (Stream wmfStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Paint.wmf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
      {
         Image replacementVectorImage = Image.GetInstance(wmfStream);
         replacementVectorImage.SetAbsolutePosition(strat.TextLocationInfo[0].TopLeft[0],     strat.TextLocationInfo[0].BottomRight[1]);
         PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
         cb.AddImage(replacementVectorImage);
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks to mkl and VahidN for your valuable input!

Answer (score 1):

- add default images as place holders.
- export your xaml files as images.
- now it's possible to replace these default images with new images. more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751517/298573

Comment: @Brandon If you use images as placeholders, please make sure your software does not create inline images but instead uses XObjects. The SO answer VahidN refers to only works with XObjects. Furthermore, XObjects can not only contain bitmap images but also text and vector graphics.

Comment: @VahidN: Thanks much, as with my above response to mkl I'm going to look into a number of these things tomorrow and come back after I've examined the ReportViewer exported PDF in a test iText environment.

Comment: So far so good! ReportViewer does export images as xObjects, but I still have the problem of identifying each image. I am unable to find any metadata, or annotations, or identifying string names, associated with the images in the PDF exported by Report Viewer. Some clean way to identify each xObject as the placeholder for chart 1, for chart 2, etc., and get its position. I'm looking into my options for this now.