# How load text position from pdf doc?

Tags: c#, vector, itext

I load pdfdoc, by:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(byteArray);
LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx st3 = new LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx();
PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1, st3);
```

Now I can get list of page elements from `st3.TextLocationInfo`. Every element has property `TopLeft` and `BottomRight`, they are `Vector`.
How can I get element position if I don't know max value of scale. I know that vector start on left bottom page corner but I don't know where is end because I don't know page size in the same scale like vector.

I can run

```
var pageSize = pdfReader.GetPageSize(1)
```

But values from vectors are bigger than pageSize `Width` and `Height`

On the other hand, can I load every char position on page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read page size by

```
var pageSize = pdfReader.GetPageSize(1)
```

next I created

```
TextInfoLocation textLocation = new TextInfoLocation(textLine.TopLeft, textLine.BottomRight, this.PdfFilePageSize);
```

Properties .TopLeft and .BottomRight are vectors.
textLine is LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx.TextInfo object read from pdfReader by strategy.

Now text position in pixels form vectores I can get from:

```
double leftMargin = textLocation.LeftMargin;
```

Answer (score 0):

`LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx` is not part of iTextSharp. I assume, therefore, you talk about the class provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8825884/1729265). That class does nothing fancy with the positions. Thus, to respond to your issue:

> I know that vector start on left bottom page corner but I don't know where is end because I don't know page size in the same scale like vector.
>
> I can run
>
> ```
> var pageSize = pdfReader.GetPageSize(1)
> ```
>
> But values from vectors are bigger than pageSize `Width` and `Height`

First of all: the coordinates you get from `LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx.TextLocationInfo` indeed are to be interpreted in the context of `pdfReader.GetPageSize`.

There are two major causes why the vector values can be beyond `Width` and `Height` of the latter:

1. The rectangle returned by `pdfReader.GetPageSize` does not need to be based in (0,0). It could e.g. have x coordinates in 301..400 and y coordinates in 501..600. In that case height and width would both be 100 but all coordinates of points in that rectangle would be higher.

   Thus, do not look at `Width` and `Height` but instead at `Left`, `Bottom`, `Right`, and `Top`.
2. Text may actually be outside the visible page and, therefore, have coordinates outside of `pdfReader.GetPageSize`.

For a final verdict please supply the PDF in question.